# Rebus Saga with Complex Data

Tags: rabbitmq, saga, rebus

I am developing a  Application in .net core 6 using Rebus Sagas. I need my Saga Data to contain an array objects that will be removed from the list once an item is processed so that the system can know when all the items in the batch has been processed. What structure can I use to hold that information or what is the best way to organization that information.

Comment: Hi, Amour  I just wanted to ask if Rebus supports .Net 6. The official wiki is not clear. Thank you.

Comment: Definitely it supports. I am using it with .net 6 already.

Answer (score 1):

I have come to an understanding that SagaData is persisted as a whole so any object in that structure will be serialized and saved to the database any time it is modified so you can put any structure in the ISageData that can be serialized and persisted.

This Solves the Problem.

Comment: Exactly  Good you figured it out